# SeriesCoefficients expansion contradicts FullSimplify

Tags: bugs, series-expansion

**Bug introduced in 9.0 or earlier and persisting through 12.2 or later**

---

Executing the following

```
SeriesCoefficient[Log[1/2 (1 + Sqrt[1 - x])], {x, 0, n}, 
   Assumptions -> {n >= 1, n ∈ Integers}]
```

I get:
[image: mma-outputs-error]
which clearly asserts that the solution should be zero identically (and can be obtained by apply `FullSimplify`)– so, did *Mathematica* make a mistake?

Comment: Please, try to be as descriptive as possible when asking questions.

Comment: What happens if you actually evaluate that beastie at nonnegative integers?

Comment: clearly a b-g.  `SeriesCoefficient` gives the correct result if you specify any particular `n`.

Comment: This bug is present even in Math 7.0.1 on win7x64.

Answer (score 9, accepted):

Here is a workaround:

```
f[x_] = Log[1/2 (1 + Sqrt[1 - x])];
```

Generate a sequence from several of the coefficients

```
seq = Table[
   SeriesCoefficient[f[x], {x, 0, n}],
   {n, 8}];
```

Find the function that generates that sequence

```
coef[n_] = FindSequenceFunction[seq, n] //
  FullSimplify
```

> -(Pochhammer[3/2, -1 + n]/
>         (4*n*Gamma[1 + n]))

For an alternative form for the coefficients

```
coef2[n_] = coef[n] // FunctionExpand
```

> -(Gamma[1/2 + n]/(2*n^2*Sqrt[Pi]*
>            Gamma[n]))

Verifying that these are the general coefficients for the original function

```
f[x] == Sum[coef[n]*x^n, {n, 1, Infinity}] == 
  Sum[coef2[n]*x^n, {n, 1, Infinity}] // Simplify
```

> True

Comment: Thanks a lot, but what's the reason mma give me the wrong outputs?

Comment: Its algorithm failed; hence the need for a workaround.

Answer (score 3):

Interesting, doing nearly the same thing as @BobHanlon:

```
 clist = CoefficientList[
        Normal@Series[Log[1/2 (1 + Sqrt[1 - x])], {x, 0, 12}], x];
 FindSequenceFunction[clist, n]
```

yields a (Correct) `DifferenceRoot` expression:

> DifferenceRoot[
>     Function[{[FormalY], [FormalN]}, {(-1 + 3 [FormalN] - 
>            2 [FormalN]^2) [FormalY][[FormalN]] + 
>         2 [FormalN]^2 [FormalY][1 + [FormalN]] == 0, [FormalY][1] ==
>         0, [FormalY][2] == -(1/4)}]][n]

The difference here is `clist` includes the `0` first term.  Not so useful but maybe it will give some insight to the cause of the error.

Comment: Use `FindSequenceFunction[Rest@clist, n] // FullSimplify` and you will get the same result as mine.